# Deciding about constructed objects at compilation time

Tags: c++, cmake

I have following problem to solve.

I have component A. This component has some sub-components - B,C,D. Using cmake I am building or not those B,C,D components. It depends on current platform configuration. My cmake system is making executable makefiles (for A component) for linking only those components, which were used in given cmake run. If component B was built, it is added to executable if not - is not linked. The same with other - C,D.

All those B,C,D components provide some implementations of interface used in A component. This A component shall manage objects created by B,C,D and keep those objects in some map, using proper object at proper time.

**Question:**

I want to achieve some simple and reliable mechanism for adding those objects implementing A interface automatically, the same as it is now with linking - linked are only modules, which were built. The same with those objects - I would like to have them registered in A component only when they were compiled.

It is hard for me to explain it. The idea is easy - *build some map of those objects at compilation time. Only components compiled shall deliver their object to this map*.

Comment: You can solve this by using preprocessor directives set by the makefile/cmake system. For example, if component B is compiled and should be included when compiling A, you can use directives such as `#ifdef COMPILED_B` to include support for B in A when necessary.

Comment: Yes, it is possible but I would like to avoid #ifdef in the source code. I just wanted to know how other people are doing it in some more sophisticated way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used designs similar to how Objective-C and Smalltalk implement methods.

In C++, methods == member functions and must be defined at compile time.  So, even though the interface can be extended with mechanisms such is the preprocessor, the same configuration must also affect any clients of the class, or they simply won't link.

So I use a message passing system to invoke methods on objects.  So if A is the main class, and you compile in C and D but not B, then the message processor of A will only respond to messages that have handlers registered by C and D.

This type of design does require having a messaging system of some sort. There are numerous existing systems such as Google Protocol Buffers and Apache Thrift.  I chose to design one since I wanted even more runtime configurability than most existing systems allow (many of these messaging systems have IDL compilers involved).

However, it did allow me to get closer to the OO realm than the mixed-paradigm language C++ typically permits.

Comment: So in your case components, which were compiled (C, D) had to have some global scope (initialized at process start) objects, which were registering itself as handlers to some global message dispatcher? They were doing it in from their constructors?

Comment: A's constructor searches a path for shared objects.  If they exist, it loads them and calls an initializer function (standard name on all components).  The initializer injects their capabilities into the messaging system by registering the method names and associated addresses.  Parameters are carried as key-value pairs as part of the message.  A new component's message API can be queried to get a list of commands, parameters, units, limits/ranges, and some description.  It's a little bit on the elaborate side, but targeted toward easy maintenance of a large distributed system.

Comment: In one specific example, the constructor is passed a string that represents the path to the components directory for this project.  Then the OS's API is used to locate and load the shared object (DLL's for the Windows build) and dynamically link in their code.  The objects include their functionality implemented as message handlers plus an init function that can inject their functionality into the messaging system.  A pointer to the message client is passed to the init function so it can make the registration calls.

Comment: Thank you for giving me good advice. I was thinking about some solution working at compilarion time, without dynamic loading of shared obkects (I have to support windows and linux platforms and it is priblematic to do it easilly)  but maybe I will consider it. Thank you

Comment: I am supporting both of those platforms as well.  I wrote an OS abstraction layer to perform most operations irrespective of the platform it is being compiled into.  It makes life very easy (relatively).

Comment: What about shared objects. Did you use some lib to handle it on both platforms with the same interface?

Comment: Yes, the aforementioned OS abstraction library.  It presents things like threads, semaphores, mutex, pipes, queues, shared library operations, etc. with the same API to the application layer.  In the back end it has small implementation modules for win32, linux, cygwin, and a couple of RTOS's.